# Android: using intent filter to launch app doesn't work

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-intent

I know this question is asked and answered many times on SO, but I just couldn't get it to work. Here is my manifest file (I have 3 activities, I'm showing the only one that I want to be displayed when associated):

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/HoloDarkTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EXTRA_TEXT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.action.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:host="example.com" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When I launch a browser and go to "example.com", my app isn't launched. Is there something wrong with the above XML?

Not sure if relevant, but this activity uses MediaPlayer to play videos. Also, I'm using SDK version 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It's simply a case of typo. Instead of this,

```
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.action.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
```

I needed to replace "android.intent.action" with "android.intent.category" in the last two lines:

```
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer here because this thread is one of the top hits when googling "intent filter to launch app from http not working". I suppose the root cause for me could also be considered a typo, but I'm going to call it an "Android documentation defect".

There's a line way toward the bottom of [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) that breaks down a URI as:

```
<scheme>://<host>:<port>/<path>
```

This breakdown indicates that the "://", ":" and "/" will be added for me so I used the following data in my `intent-filter`:

```
<data android:scheme="http" />
<data android:host="my.school.edu" />
<data android:path="thingy" />
```

I then sent myself an SMS with the following text: "my.school.edu/thingy", which was recognized by my SMS client (Hangouts) as a web address, so it made it clickable. However, clicking on it just gave me a choice of browsers, my app was a no-show.

So I removed the host and the path, and my app launched for any link (or at least every one I tried). I put the host back in and it still worked. Put the path back and we're back to not working. On a whim I decided to prepend a slash to the path:

```
<data android:path="/thingy" />
```

...et voilà! There's my app in amongst the browsers! So the error in my view is Android's doc that suggests that the slash is inserted automagically. :) It apparently is not.

More Info: I'm using the HTTP scheme because that's what gets made clickable in SMS and email messages, giving me a free ride to that point.

And note that if you specify a unique host (and path), and the user selects "Always" when choosing your app from the list, future taps on your link will bypass that choice dialog and go straight to your app, which is nice.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you have the internet permission in your manifest.

Comment: Not required for simple app launching. I saw this because I was having trouble getting this to work and found this thread. I added the "internet permission" (actually android.permission.INTERNET) and still had the same problem.  I eventually got it working (see my answer elsewhere in this thread), then took this permission out and it still worked.

Answer (score -2):

I doubt that you can override the `http` scheme to point back to your app.

Comment: I just tried replacing "http" with a customized scheme "myscheme" and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You can use the http scheme to launch your app, it's just that it'll launch all the browsers too.